# How to get ng-value from List (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need a static value from list tag when click or touch in mobile individually. how to get it in angularjs

```
    <ion-list ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ion-item menu-close ng-value="apple">
                     Apple
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close ng-value="orange">
                      Orange
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close ng-value="pineapple">
                         PineApple
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close ng-value="mango">
                   Mango
    </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

angularjs

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    })
```

Comment: It's not clear what you need probably that should be `<ion-item menu-close>{{apple}}</ion-item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using href: http://plnkr.co/edit/35wTi7?p=info

Here's a working example using ng-click: http://plnkr.co/edit/NN4cWr?p=preview

These examples are dynamic, but you'll get the point.The second example is much better in your case.

This is what you want to do:

### HTML:

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-click="someFunction('apple')">
    Apple
</ion-item>
<ion-item menu-close ng-click="someFunction('orange')">
    Apple
</ion-item>
```

### JavaScript

```
// We must use .dot notation with Ionic 
$scope.fruit = {
    selected : ''
};

$scope.someFunction= function(id) { 
    console.log(id); // Will print apple
    $scope.fruit.selected = id;
}
```

My examples are also called a Master-Detail pattern, click [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-5-master-detail-pattern/) to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear to me what you need, but to bind a value to the HTML just populate the scope and use it:

HTML:

```
<ion-list ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ion-item menu-close>{{apple}}</ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

JS:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.apple = "This is an apple";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this example from Angular documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue#example